# .net Core System.InvalidOperationException The instance of entity type 'Etapa' cannot be tracked

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm developing a web API with Angular and .Net Core. When I try to do an update at this endpoint, I get this error:

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request. `System.InvalidOperationException`: The instance of entity type 'Etapa' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdEtapa'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.ThrowIdentityConflict(InternalEntityEntry entry)     
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.IdentityMap`1.Add(TKey key, InternalEntityEntry entry, Boolean updateDuplicate)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.StartTracking(InternalEntityEntry entry)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.PaintAction(EntityEntryGraphNode node, Boolean 
force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityEntryGraphIterator.TraverseGraph[TState](EntityEntryGraphNode node, TState state, Func`3 handleNode)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.EntityGraphAttacher.AttachGraph(InternalEntityEntry rootEntry, EntityState entityState, Boolean forceStateWhenUnknownKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState(InternalEntityEntry entry, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Update[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.Update(TEntity entity)
   at Foha.Repositories.DataRepository`1.Update(T entity) in C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Foha\Repositories\DataRepository.cs:line 22
   at Foha.Controllers.EtapaController.PutEtapa(Int32 id, EditEtapaDto editEtapaDto) in C:\Users\Federico\Desktop\Foha\Controllers\EtapaController.cs:line 208 "
```

This is the Controller:

```
namespace Foha.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EtapaController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly fohaContext _context;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly IDataRepository<Etapa> _repo;
        private readonly IDataRepository<EtapaEmpleado> _repo2;

        public EtapaController(fohaContext context, IMapper mapper, 
        IDataRepository<Etapa> repo,IDataRepository<EtapaEmpleado> repo2)
        {

            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
            _repo = repo;
            _repo2 = repo2;
        }

       [HttpPut("{id}")]
       public async Task<IActionResult> PutEtapa([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] 
       EditEtapaDto editEtapaDto)
       { 
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
         return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }

       if (id != editEtapaDto.IdEtapa)
       {
         return BadRequest();
       }

    // _context.Entry(editEtapaDto).State = EntityState.Detached;
    
       var preEtapa = _mapper.Map<Etapa>(editEtapaDto);
    
       //Prueba
       foreach(var a in preEtapa.EtapaEmpleado)
       {
          var preEtapaEmpleado=_mapper.Map<EtapaEmpleado>(a);
         
if(_context.EtapaEmpleado.Where(z=>z.IdEmpleado==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEmpleado).Count()>0 && _context.EtapaEmpleado.Where(x=>x.IdEtapa==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEtapa).Count()>0)
        {
            var tiempoAntes=_context.EtapaEmpleado.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(z=>z.IdEmpleado==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEmpleado && z.IdEtapa==preEtapaEmpleado.IdEtapa);
            var condicion=String.IsNullOrEmpty(tiempoAntes.TiempoParc);
            //SI ESTA PAUSADO O FINALIZADO
            if(condicion==false)
            {
                string[] arrTAntesStr=tiempoAntes.TiempoParc.Split(':');
                string[] arrTDespuesStr=preEtapaEmpleado.TiempoParc.Split(':');
                int[] tiempoAntesArrInt= Array.ConvertAll(arrTAntesStr,Int32.Parse);
                int[] tiempoDespuesArrInt=Array.ConvertAll(arrTDespuesStr,Int32.Parse);
                int[] tiempoIntFinal={0,0,0,0};
                int meLlevoUno=0;
                string tiempoStringFinal=null;
                
                for(int i=3;i>-1;i--)
                {
                    switch(i){
                        default:
                            tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                            meLlevoUno=tiempoIntFinal[i]/60;
                            tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoIntFinal[i]%60;
                            break;
                        case 0:
                                tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                                break;
                        case 1:
                            tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoAntesArrInt[i]+tiempoDespuesArrInt[i]+meLlevoUno;
                            meLlevoUno=tiempoIntFinal[i]/24;
                            tiempoIntFinal[i]=tiempoIntFinal[i]%24;
                            break;
                    }
                }

                
                var builder = new StringBuilder();
                for(int j=0;j<tiempoIntFinal.Length;j++)
                {
                    if(tiempoIntFinal[j]<10)
                    {
                        builder.Append("0");
                    }
                    builder.Append(tiempoIntFinal[j]);
                    if(j!=3)
                    {
                        builder.Append(":");    
                    }
                    
                    tiempoStringFinal=builder.ToString();
                }   

                preEtapaEmpleado.TiempoParc=tiempoStringFinal;
            }
            
            try{
                _repo2.Update(preEtapaEmpleado);
            }
            catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException){
                throw;
            }
        }
        else{
            try{

                _repo2.Add(preEtapaEmpleado);
            }
            catch(DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        await _repo2.SaveAsync(preEtapaEmpleado);
    }
    
    //IN THE NEXT LINE IS THE PROBLEM    
    _repo.Update(preEtapa);
    await _repo.SaveAsync(preEtapa);
    return StatusCode(201,preEtapa);
}
```

This is my `IDataRepository`:

```
namespace Foha.Repositories
{
    public interface IDataRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        void Add(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        Task<T> SaveAsync(T entity);
    }
}
```

DataRepository:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Foha.Models;

namespace Foha.Repositories
{
    public class DataRepository<T> : IDataRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly fohaContext _context;

        public DataRepository(fohaContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public void Add(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        }

        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _context.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }

        public async Task<T> SaveAsync(T entity)
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Foha.Models
{
    public partial class Etapa
    {
        public int IdEtapa { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoEtapa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateIni { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateFin { get; set; }
        public bool? IsEnded { get; set; }
        public string TiempoParc { get; set; }
        public string TiempoFin { get; set; }
        public int? IdTransfo { get; set; }
        public int? IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        
        public string Hora { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InicioProceso { get; set; }
        public int? IdColor { get; set; }
        public int? NumEtapa{get;set;}

        
        public Colores IdColorNavigation { get; set; }
        public TipoEtapa IdTipoEtapaNavigation { get; set; }
        public Transformadores IdTransfoNavigation { get; set; }

        public ICollection<EtapaEmpleado> EtapaEmpleado {get;set;}
    }
}
```

DTO:

```
namespace Foha.Dtos
{
    public class EditEtapaDto
    {
        public int IdEtapa { get; set; }
        public int? IdTipoEtapa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateIni { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateFin { get; set; }
        public bool? IsEnded { get; set; }
        public string TiempoParc { get; set; }
        public string TiempoFin { get; set; }
        public int? IdTransfo { get; set; }
        public int? IdEmpleado { get; set; }
        
        public string Hora { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InicioProceso { get; set; }
        public int? IdColor { get; set; }
        public int? NumEtapa{get;set;}

        
        public Colores IdColorNavigation { get; set; }
        public TipoEtapa IdTipoEtapaNavigation { get; set; }
        public Transformadores IdTransfoNavigation { get; set; }

        public ICollection<EtapaEmpleado> EtapaEmpleado {get;set;}
    }
}
```

I tried to find an answer in another posts, but I couldn't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: What do your entities look like? See if this answer applies to you - he needed a public setter on his id field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61913652/cant-update-value-primary-key-has-a-temporary-value-while-attempting-to-chan?noredirect=1#comment109511942_61913652

Comment: @Nikki9696, I can´t post all my entity because doesn't fit in this comment, but my entity is some like this: 

`namespace Foha.Models
{
    public partial class Etapa
    {
        public int IdEtapa { get; set; }
        public DateTime? InicioProceso { get; set; }
        public int? IdColor { get; set; }
        public int? NumEtapa{get;set;}
        ...
        ...
        public TipoEtapa IdTipoEtapaNavigation { get; set; }
        public Transformadores IdTransfoNavigation { get; set; }
        public ICollection<EtapaEmpleado> EtapaEmpleado {get;set;}
    }
}`

Comment: all with public setters and getters

Comment: Can you show us the implementation class of the interface, and at which line occurs the error? You can edit your post to do some updates. Here is a  similiar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57450937/the-instance-of-entity-type-model-cannot-be-tracked-because-another-instance-wit) which may be helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, i added the model, the DTO, and a comment in the controller to say what is the line of the error.

Comment: You're asking a question about EF Core but didn't post any EF Core code. EF Core has no `IDataRepository` nor does it need one - `DbSet` already is a repository, adding another "generic" repository on top only causes trouble. Eg that `SaveChanges` can easily perform 2 DELETEs and 5 INSERTs, while you've lost the ability to configure your context and sets. You have to re-configure them each time now

Comment: Check [the PUT example in the ASP.NET Core tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#the-puttodoitem-method). Notice how simple it is compared to your code. It attaches the entity with `_context.Entry(todoItem).State = EntityState.Modified;` and calls `SaveChangesAsync()`. No attempt to load the entry in advance. If you *do* load it first, you need to update *that* entity

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i'm really new on this, sorry about the unnecesary code. So,  ¿are you tell me that i have to delete the IDataRepository Interface?

Comment: Try with *simple* code first, that does the job. Patterns are only meant to be used when they solve a specific problem. What problem are you trying to solve that you needed to add that repository? What does all this code do, why the *double* conversions? Your DbContext seems to contain `EtapaEmpleado` objects, not `Etapa`. In all this code it's possible you tried to store the wrong type

Comment: In your case, you have some REST DTOs you want to save to the database. This means you only need *one* mapping from `EditEtapaDto` to `EtapaEmpleadoDto`. Once you do that you can easily attach all entities in a 3-line loop and call `SaveChangesAsync` at the end.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, about the simple code first, you are right. When i started this project i thought that was the best solution. 
My db Context contains the two objects, but because an Etapa can have an EtapaEmpleado, i tried to add an EtapaEmpleado in this update (Is an implementation of a process that has many employers).
I will try to do the mapping that you are tell me, and i will try to refactor this code. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: As I posted above, patterns are like medicine. They are meant to solve *specific* problems, in specific cases. That's part of the "official" definition: `A solution to a problem in a context`. Used improperly, they have side-effects.